# Don't pass or ignore arguments in a dynamic call by using getattr function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've created a Filter builder in my application and I would like to improve it removing unnecessary parameters Value=None of my functions popular and unanswered, working like javascript for example.
The querystring parameters can be: none (all records), popular=1, unanswered=1, by=username

*filters.py*

```
class Filters:
    queryset = None

    def apply(self, queryset):
        self.queryset = queryset

        for key, value in self.request.items():
            if key in self.filters and hasattr(self, key):
                return getattr(self, key)(value)

        return self.queryset


class ThreadFilter(Filters):
    filters = ('by', 'popular', 'unanswered')
    request = None

    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    def by(self, username):
        return self.queryset.filter(username=username)

    def popular(self, value=None):
        return self.queryset.order_by('-replies_count')

    def unanswered(self, value=None):
        return self.queryset.filter(replies_count=0)
```

*views.py*

```
class ThreadsView(generic.ListView):
    model = Thread
    template_name = "threads/index.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        thread_filter = ThreadFilter(self.request.GET)

        threads = thread_filter.apply(Thread.objects.all())

        channel_slug = self.kwargs.get('channel_slug', False)

        if channel_slug:
            threads = threads.filter(channel__slug=channel_slug)

        return threads
```

To be clear, I'm looking for an elegant way to avoid a logical test since I'm beginner in Python and it can be done in other languages like php

```
if value == "1": 
    return getattr(self, key) 

return getattr(self, key)(value)
```

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. If you don't want your `popular` and `unanswered` methods to have a `value=None` argument, then just delete `value=None` from the function's argument list.

Comment: I got this error
popular() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Maybe some logic to test if the method has parameters before call getattr function

Comment: Those `value` parameters aren't unnecessary, because the code in `apply` calls those methods with an argument: `return getattr(self, key)(value)`. You can't remove them without breaking your code.

Comment: Exactly. I was looking for a elegant alternative of

if value == "1":
    return getattr(self, key)
return getattr(self, key)(value)

Comment: replace `value=None` with `*args` maybe?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found was check the number of parameters

```
class Filters:
    queryset = None

    def apply(self, queryset):
        self.queryset = queryset

        for key, value in self.request.items():
            if key in self.filters and hasattr(self, key):
                count_param = eval('self.%s.__code__.co_argcount' % key)
                if count_param < 2:
                    return getattr(self, key)

                return getattr(self, key)(value)

        return self.queryset
```